# Android phone causing visual glitch with object duplication in Unity game camera view - how can I troubleshoot?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Few Details about my game project (in Unity)

- it's a 2D game (with an orthographic camera)
- using URP (2D Renderer)
- I am using 2 cameras - 1st Camera (Main) follows the player and 2nd is for Minimap

My Android game is running very smoothly (without this issue) on most of the android devices but on some android phones camera seems to duplicate objects that are present in the game view, one thing to take note of is it's only duplicating objects that either a part of Minimap or it has a 3d mesh render (i have few 3d objects in my game) - please refer - img1 & img2 for better understanding

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwmrp.png)

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJSqO.png)

I tried everything but nothing seems to fix this issue,

I really appreciate any help you can provide.